# Drag formula without changing value

Tags: google-sheets

I have the formula

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B48), "",MINUS(B48,B2))
```

Where 48 should be the current row number
(so the formula for row 40 is:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B40), "",MINUS(B40,B2))
```

b2 is always the same.
I try to apply this formula to multiple rows, but when I drag the formula It updates the b2 value.
So for every row I have to update the b2 value.
Is there a way to apply the formula to multiple lines (the best would be the whole column after row 2) without having to change the b2 value for every row?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *"freeze"* the cell `B2` by using the dollar sign `$` and use **`B$2`** instead.

Then your formula will be:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B48), "",MINUS(B48,B$2))
```

You can take it a step further by using an arrayformula:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(B30:B55), "",MINUS(B30:B55,B$2)))
```

(please adjust the ranges as needed)

Function [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275).

Comment: The arrayformula does make it a lot easier. Don't you agree?